# Doctrine 2 @joincolumns

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have two entities Page and File. One Page has many Files. My other entities also have many Files, so I join Page and File by two columns (entity_id and entity_type). When I have sample data and I get it, everything work ok. I found problem when I tried to add Page and Files to db, Files get ID from Page but dont'get entity_type.

Creating entities:

```
 $page = new \CmsIr\Page\Entity\Page();
 $page->exchangeArray($form->getData());
 $page->setEntityType('page');

 $this->getEm()->persist($page);
 $this->getEm()->flush();

 foreach($scannedDirectory as $file) {
     $mimeType = $this->getFileService()->getMimeContentType($this->uploadDir . '/' . $file);

     $pageFile = new \CmsIr\File\Entity\File();
     $pageFile->setFilename($file);
     $pageFile->setPage($page);
     $pageFile->setMimeType($mimeType);

     $this->getEm()->persist($pageFile);
     $this->getEm()->flush();                       
 }
```

Error looks like:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO cms_file (entity_type, entity_id, filename, mime_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, 5, "140343_las-promienie-slonca-56c9a66d27830.jpg", "image\/jpeg; charset=binary"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_type' cannot be null
```

Page:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="cms_page")
*/
class Page
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $name;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $subtitle;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $url;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $entity_type;

/**
*  @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CmsIr\System\Entity\Status")
*  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $status;

/** @ORM\Column(type="text") */
protected $content;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $filename;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CmsIr\File\Entity\File", mappedBy="page")
 */
protected $files;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->files = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

File:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="cms_file")
*/
class File
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $entity_type;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
protected $entity_id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="text") */
protected $filename;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $mime_type;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CmsIr\Page\Entity\Page")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type", referencedColumnName="entity_type"),
 * })
**/
protected $page;
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to insert a file with `entity_type` `null` into your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see from your `Page` entity definition, `entity_type` is defined as `integer`:

`/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
protected $entity_type;`

In your code snippet here:

`$page->setEntityType('page');`

You are passing in a string value.

My solution to this would be to get the reference of the `entity_type` you are trying to set it as before calling the setter method.

Essentially, your setter method should be accepting an instance of the `entity_type` entity, an Object and not a String.

Hope this at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a little mess in your code. At the top you set:

```
$page->setEntityType('page');
```

while `entity_type` is defined later as integer:

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
protected $entity_type;
```

Then you want to make a reference from `File` to `Page` where you're setting in annotation `@ORM\JoinColumns(...)`.

You don't need to do any of that. Use the simple format for [One-to-Many](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) which automatically creates `page_id` column for you.

In your case:

```
class File {
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="files")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $page;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: My bad, I was trying many options with integer and string. `entity_type` is defined as string.

I need to do it like that, because many entites join with `File`:
`Page`, `Post`, `Slider`